# Unwanted string inserted into URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are trying to build a Rails web-application, and there has been this weird issue with random string being inserted to the URL right after the host domain (haven't seen it happening anywhere else in the URL). One example is like this:

```
https://www.<domain>.com/ZQpfZ/<some route>
```

This bug/error doesn't seem to be happen every time, but definitely a bit unpredictably as we generate this URL using path helpers from Rails. Another occasion that this would happen is I would directly type into the URL bar: `www.<domain>.com`, and it occasionally would insert some random string right after I press enter (with no auto-fill) as such:

```
https://www.<domain>.com/d4rsQf
```

What would be the reason for this and how should we go about solving this? It has been causing a lot of problem as we have been sending email with account confirmation link embedded, and sometimes the link won't work just because of the random string being added.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.